# Create an autoload alias for an autoload function

Tags: vimscript, functions, autoload

I have a function like this in `autoload/foo/bar.vim`:

```
function! foo#bar#do_stuff(...) abort
  " do stuff
  return
endfunction
```

Is it possible to create an "alias" for this function, without defining a wrapper function and passing args with `call()`?

I tried this in `autoload/quux.vim`:

```
let quux#do_stuff = function('foo#bar#do_stuff')
```

But I got an error saying that "Funcref variable name must start with a capital".

Is there some other way to define an alias like this? Or must I write an actual wrapper function?

Answer (score 2):

May I ask why do you want to address this function through another name?

If you need an indirection

```
let SomeRef = function('foo#bar#do_stuff')
```

works correctly. You can define as many variables as you want (that respect Vim naming policy for function-reference variables), but you won't be able to define functions this way.

Comment: I wanted to create an alias for backward compatibility in a plugin, so creating an alias with the wrong name doesn't help. So I want it to be autoloaded and namespaced in the same way as the other functions in the same file. So the answer is "no, it's not possible" then?

Comment: @shadowtalker Indeed. As far as I know, this is not possible. In my plugins, I kept the old function, add a "notify once" message about the deprecation, and forward the call to the new function, like I do here: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/6cb8f4cbe54b735dfa6dbb708cc9eaddead251d2/autoload/lh/buffer/dialog.vim#L353

Answer (score 0):

As per Luc Hermitte, this is indeed not possible with Vimscript.

You should upvote their answer, but I am posting this so I can mark the question as "answered".